# ListGrid doesn't want to set the width of the delete-button column

Tags: smartgwt

On a ListGrid, when you enable to remove a record there is a cross image stand on each record line.
Is it possible de resize this column ?
When I ask for the list of fields of listGrid it give me

```
for (ListGridField field : listGrid.getFields()) {
  System.out.println("'" + field.getName() + "'");
}
```

A list of column name then a column whose name is "$54h"... I think it is the name for the delete button column.

But it seems that this code :

```
for (ListGridField field : listGrid.getFields()) {
  field.setWidth("100%");
}
listGrid.getField("$54h").setWidth(60);
```

does not produce what I want : means my delete-button column is not 60px width.

Does anyone understand why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem use

```
ListGridField removeFieldProperties = new ListGridField("View-delete", "Delete this record", 40);
listGrid.setRemoveFieldProperties(removeFieldProperties);
```